# Is there a way to close and open a VBA macro while running and start running again?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that opens up ETABS using API, but the command `myETABSObject.ApplicationStart` sometimes doesn't work, it gets stuck while opening ETABS. I would like to know if there is a way to force quit ETABS, close and open Excel, and then start running the macro again?

```
If AttachToInstance Then
    'attach to a running instance of ETABS
    'get the active ETABS object
    Set myETABSObject = GetObject(, "CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")
  Else
    If SpecifyPath Then
      'create an instance of the ETABS object from the specified path
      Set myETABSObject = myHelper.CreateObject(ProgramPath)
    Else
      'create an instance of the ETABS object from the latest installed ETABS
      Set myETABSObject = myHelper.CreateObjectProgID("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")
    End If
    'start ETABS application
    myETABSObject.ApplicationStart 
  End If
```

Comment: AFAIK with a Macro written in Excel, there's no way to have it close the Excel Application completely, reopen, and resume a macro.

Comment: Any macro you would be running will end when the root instance of excel is closed.

Comment: functions are invoked either from excel application root or from inside other functions, normally after execution of a called function is done, control is returned to the root/master function or application and by any chance, if any of them are closed, the control will be lost. In a very specific condition there is a workaround to change the root to a different instance or function, but it is very hard to implement and I tried myself and realized that if you get to that point, it means your design is not good

Comment: why do you think that you have to restart excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments, it's not possible. But you can do a very crude workaround.

Create a sub that runs when the workbook is opened. This sub will contain the code that you want to run again. But the first step of the sub should be checking some parameter, so it wouldn't run every time you open it, but only on restart. The parameter can be for example a value in some cell, that you put there before you closed the workbook.

Now the only problem is how to open the workbook once it is closed. You can create a helper Excel workbook, also with a sub that run when the workbook is opened. The only thing that the sub does is to set a timer and after the wait period, it opens the workbook you want to restart. You need to open the helper workbook before closing the other one.

This should get you what you need. Of course, it is nothing you can publish, but for your purposes (e.g. weekly report) should be fine.